# How is the 'apply ' method executed under the hood?

Tags: javascript, methods, apply

I have not understood the apply method in Javascript. From what I understood was the first parameter in the apply will be the desired value for the key word this, and the extra parameter would apply to the function the apply borrowed. I am still not sure how this apply method under the hood. How can the result be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

```
var flattenedArray = [[1,2],[3,4,5,6], 7, 8]
[].concat.apply([],flattenedArray)
```

Could anyone help me how it actually works on this scenerio, please. Thanks

Comment: Every function has a context attached to it. It is represented as `[[methodName, context, args]]`. You are replacing this `context`

Comment: `apply` takes arguments as an array, and `flattenedArray` happens to be one - perfect match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` is not the value of [**Function#apply**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), but the function [**Array#concat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

`apply` only calls the function on the *explicitly bound context* and optionally takes parameters as array, which will be passed to the function.

When you pass `[[1,2],[3,4,5,6], 7, 8]` to the function `apply` it gets the inner items (the outer which keeps the inner items is considered to be the type of the 2nd parameter of `apply`, which is an array, so why it gets the inner items one by one and omit the outer array) which are `[1,2]` , `[3,4,5,6]`, `7` and `8` to the function concat.

See the example. The below two calls of *concat* are identical.

```js
const flattenedArray = [[1,2],[3,4,5,6], 7, 8];

const first = [].concat.apply([],flattenedArray);
console.log(first);

const second = [].concat([1,2], [3,4,5,6], 7, 8);
console.log(second);
```

Comment: So from your post, and from what I understood about "apply" method was that it borrowed built-in method [ ].concat to concatenate the elements of the outer array. (In this case, the outer which keeps the inner elements ([1,2], [3, 4, 5,6], 7, 8). ). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var flattenedArray = [[1,2],[3,4,5,6], 7, 8]
> [].concat.apply([],flattenedArray)
> ```

```js
                        // [].concat.apply([],flattenedArray) 
var concat = [].concat  // ^^^^^^^^^
var me = []             //                 ^^

                        // [[1,2],[3,4,5,6], 7, 8]
var arg0 = [1,2]        //  ^^^^^
var arg1 = [3,4,5,6]    //        ^^^^^^^^^
var arg2 = 7            //                   ^
var arg3 = 8            //                      ^

me.concat = concat
var res = me.concat(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3)
delete me.concat

console.log(res)
```

```js
function concat(...args) {
  var res = []
  
  for (var x of this) {
    res.push(x)
  }
  
  for (var arg of args) {
    if (arg instanceof Array) {
      for (var x of arg) {
        res.push(x)
      }
    } else {
      res.push(arg)
    }
  }
  
  return res
}

console.log(concat.apply([], [[1,2], [3,4,5,6], 7, 8]))
```